# Can't import some .mov files into Adobe Premiere, it says "Codec missing or unavailable"

Tags: premiere, file-formats, codec

I am trying to import some .mov files into Adobe Premiere project, but I keep getting the following error message "Codec missing or unavailable", this only happen for certain .mov videos which have been recorded with certain camera, but videos from other camera like canon with the same extension .mov can be imported without any trouble.

I've tried to install K-lite codec package but it didn't make a difference in Adobe Premiere. 
I've read somewhere on the web that not all the .mov files are the same and that the .mov extension is only a wrapper. The inner formation of the file may differ from one .mov file to another.
I've opened the file with the GSpot tool to get some info and here is the output:

```
qt  : Apple QuickTime (.MOV/QT)
File Type: QuickTime (.MOV)
Mime Type: video/quicktime
Recommended Display Size: 1920 x 1080
Created:     2013 Jun 06   17:53:53
Modified:    2013 Jun 22   01:10:47
codec:xdvc name: unkown
frms:146
kbps:36774
qf:0.709
pics/s: 25000
sar:1.778 (16:9)
dar: 1.778 (16:9)
```

Comment: What version of premiere are you using? Apparently, native support for it was added in June 2013 with CC. http://forums.adobe.com/message/5315765

Answer (score 1):

First off, codec packs are often more problem than they are worth.  They tend to cause conflicts as much or more than resolve them.  You are far better off targeting the particular codec that is needed.  If you look at the information about the clip, it should indicate the codec that is used within the MOV and you should then be able to get that particular codec for your machine.

From the info you listed.  It appears to be an XDCAM format.  I would recommend going to the camera manufacturer's website and looking for their XDCAM codec.  If you can't find it, I suggest posting the actual camera model here.